# Carrierwave - Define subversion retroactively

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

In carrierwaveupload you define versions, and you can define subversions like this:

```
version :square do
  process :make_square
  version :large do
    process :scale [800, 800]
  end
  version :small do
    process :scale [200,200]
  end
end
```

Is there any way i can just define the version (`:square`) and then make a function that takes all versions and adds the same subversions to them (`:large, :small`) retroactivly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have some version and need to create another versions you can use `:reprocess` method:

```
User.all.each {|m| m.avatar.recreate_versions! }
```

If simple need create image version from another version during image uploading you can use `:from_version` method

```
class MyUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  version :thumb do
    process resize_to_fill: [280, 280]
  end

  version :small_thumb, from_version: :thumb do
    process resize_to_fill: [20, 20]
  end

end
```

Comment: `from_version: :thumb` looks like what i need